# how to update nested json array using meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am want to insert these values into mongodb and here is my code, i am able to insert it but when  i was updating only access_policy inside admin_section, i was not able to do that, can anyone please help me, how can i solve it :
meteor.json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555ebffa7c88507a4a683e81"),
    "section_id" : "Admin Section",
    "is_active" : true,
    "admin_section" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "info" : "Setup custom access policy for user groups",
            "sub_section" : "Setup - access policy",
            "access_policy" : "ROOT"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "info" : "Customize access policy for main sections",
            "sub_section" : "Manage - access policy",
            "access_policy" : "ROOT"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "info" : "Manage user groups for DX-Client application",
            "sub_section" : "Manage - user groups",
            "access_policy" : "ROOT"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "info" : "Manage users for DX-Client application",
            "sub_section" : "Create - user",
            "access_policy" : "ADMINISTRATOR"
        },
    ],
    "access_policy" : "ADMINISTRATOR"
     }
```

meteor.html

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        {{#each temp_admin_section}}
          {{#if admin_section}}
              <tr class="bgLight">
                    <td class="left" id="one"><b>{{ section_id }}</b></td> 
                    <td class="left" id="two"><b>RESTRICTED</b> - <code contenteditable="true" class="edited"><input value="{{ access_policy }}" /></code><a class="add-access pull-right">add</a></td>
               </tr>
          {{#each admin_section}}
               <tr>
                  <td class="left" id="one">{{ sub_section }}</td> 
                  <td class="left" id="two">RESTRICTED - <code contenteditable="true" class="edited">
                  <input value="{{ access_policy }}" /></code></td>
              </tr>
          {{/each}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

meteor.js

```
 'change .edited': function(event, template){
  var to = event.target.value;
  var list = to.split(",");
   map.update(
    {"_id": this._id, "admin_section._id" : 1}, 
    {$set: {"admin_section.$.access_policy": list}}
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All client-side code is considered untrusted unless you call a `Meteor.call` and let a server-side method do the update. If you look in the console, you will probably see an error like this:

```
 {
  error: 403, 
  reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.", 
  details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", 
  errorType: "Meteor.Error"
}
```

On the client-side, you can only update 1 document at a time, and you must choose the document to update by ID, so the 1st argument needs to be a mongo document ID, not a mongo selector:

```
MyCollection.update(
  this._id, 
  {
    $set: { "admin_section.1.access_policy": "TEST" }
  }
)
```

Also, to update a sub-document of an array, rather than specifying the ID in the 1st argument as a selector, notice how I am specifying the ID inside the `$set` statement.

If you want to update all elements in the array, you have to loop through all of them individually:

```
var doc = MyCollection.findOne(this._id);
var adminSections = doc.admin_section;

for (i = 0; i < adminSections.length; i++) {
  // If you need to access a value in the nested doc:
  var nestedDoc = adminSections[i];
  MyCollection.update(
    this._id,
    { 
      $set: { "admin_section." + (i+1) + ".access_policy": "someValue" } 
    }
  );
{
```

Comment: it work only for first array of "admin_section", but i have to update "access_policy" each and every array as dynamic according to Id of an array, Please help.

Comment: See updated answer - is that what you're looking for?